# Is there a way to delete multiple users at once from Realm Studio?

Tags: realm, realm-js

Is there a way to list all users for a Realm instance from Realm's API? I wanted to list and delete all regular users with a script, since I can't multi select from Realm studio. They have to be deleted 1 by 1.